# Doubling measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a fixed finite measure on $\mathbb R$. We say that $\mu$ is doubling if there exists a constant $C>0$, such that for any two adjacent intervals $I=[x−h,x]$ and $J=[x,x+h]$, $$C^{−1}\mu(I)≤\mu(J)≤C\mu(I).$$ 
Assuming that $\mu$ is doubling, show that there exist positive constants $B$ and $a$, such that for every interval $I$, $$\mu(I)≤B[length(I)]^a$$

By Radon-Nikodim, I solved but I use the fact that $\mu$ is absolutely continous with respect to Lebesgue measure, but I don't know to prove this last part, i.e., that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue.

Comment: A doubling measure is not necessarily absolutely continuous (see wikipedia).
The statement that you want to prove is (a special case of) Lemma 2.1 of _On the $\overline{\partial}$ equation in weighted $L^2$ norms in $C^1$_, Michael Christ, J. Geom. Anal. 1 (1991), no. 3, 193–230, [MR1120680](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1120680).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove Property of Doubling Measure on $\mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305912/prove-property-of-doubling-measure-on-mathbbr)

Comment: ^ this proves the statement that's the actual goal of this post, not the false statement that the OP hoped to use for it.